# android map adds currentLocation marker away from blue dot

Tags: android, dictionary

I am working on google map api v2. I have a button that adds marker to my current location.

Map can get my location right but sometimes (not every time) when i want to add marker to that location, marker goes far away from the blue dot.

I want to add my marker exactly on blue dot.

[image]

and this is my code for findMe button:

```
ImageButton findMyLocation_btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.findme);
    if (findMyLocation_btn != null) {
        findMyLocation_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                    buildAlertMessageNoGps();
                } else {
                    currentLocation = mMap.getMyLocation();

                    if ( marker1 == null && currentLocation != null) {
                        new onMyLocationClick().execute();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

and onMyLocationClick()

```
private class onMyLocationClick extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {


            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this);
            List<Address> list = null;
            try {
                list = gc.getFromLocation(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), 1);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (list != null) {
                add = list.get(0);
            }
            try {
                origin = new LatLng(add.getLatitude(),add.getLongitude());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (Object o){

            createMarker(add.getLatitude(), add.getLongitude(), add.getLocality(), add.getSubLocality());
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Google Maps doc:

> This method was deprecated. use com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi instead. FusedLocationProviderApi provides improved location finding and power usage and is used by the "My Location" blue dot.

The code to get current location is something like this:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
        getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager
        .getBestProvider(criteria, false));
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
```

For more advance solution you can use FusedLocationProvider as mentioned by google: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#GetLocation